# Card Actions are no longer working for Users using a Teams Bot, because "This card action is disabled, because you've blocked ."

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, teams-toolkit

I have a teams Bot (https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-icebreaker), that worked flawless for about 3 Years, but now all of the Users can't use the Card Actions any longer, because the Error message "This card action is disabled, because you've blocked .".

Does anyone have experienced any kind of similar issue? I don't know where to start looking for a fix.

I tried to redeploy the bot with all the latest commits, but i didn't help.

I tried on the Phone, and actually it is working there. The issue only appears in the Desktop App and the Web-App.

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try below steps:

1. Navigate to MS Teams Admin centre
   (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/)
2. Enable sideloading and external apps
3. Restart Teams

There might be chances of this app being blocked by Admin. So, it's better to try that out by contacting with your admin.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-teams-overview#external-apps